# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 5

Tags: java

Tengo un problema en un proyecto de recursividad, el error que me muestra es "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"
El proyecto es un juego de TaTeTi o TicTacToe en el cual se ingresan jugadas con coordenadas y luego se anuncia el ganador.

Si alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo es un proyecto urgente, copio el codigo:

```
package laboratorio;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Laboratorio {
    static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
        static  int c = 0;
        static int f = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            menu(); 


    }

    public static void menu()
    {
        char matriz [][] = new char[3][3];
        char jugador = 'X';  


        System.out.println("");  
        System.out.println("0 - Salir"); 
        System.out.println("1 - Comenzar juego"); 
        System.out.println("Elija un punto del menu anterior");
        int menu = entrada.nextInt();

        if (menu == 1)
        {    
            llenarMatriz(matriz, 0, 0);
            imprimirMatriz(matriz,0,0);
            System.out.println();
            gestionarTurnos(matriz, jugador);

        }
        else if (menu == 0) {
            System.exit(menu);            
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(); 
            System.out.println("Debe ingresar una opcion de menu correcta");
            menu(); 
        }

    }



    public static void llenarMatriz (char [][] matriz, int f, int c)
    {       
        matriz[f][c] = '-';
        if(c != matriz[0].length -1 || f!=matriz.length -1) //Estoy en la ultima columna 
        {
            if(c == matriz[0].length - 1)
            {               
                f++; //Paso a la siguiente fila
                c = 0; //Comienza de la primer columna

            }
            else {
                c++;                  
            }
            llenarMatriz(matriz, f, c);  
        }


    }

    public static void imprimirMatriz (char matriz [][], int f, int c)
    {       
        System.out.print(matriz[f][c] + ""); //muestro el primer elemento

        if(c != matriz[0].length -1 || f!=matriz.length -1) //Estoy en la ultima columna 
        {
            if(c == matriz[0].length - 1)
            {
                f++; //Paso a la siguiente fila
                c = 0; //Comienza de la primer columna
                System.out.println(); 
            }
            else {
                c++; 
            }
            imprimirMatriz(matriz, f, c);  
        }

    }


   public static boolean comprobarCasilla (char [][] matriz, int fila, int columna)
    {
        String guionaux = "-";
        char guion = guionaux.charAt(0);
        boolean esta = false;
        if (matriz[fila][columna] == guion && fila<=matriz.length -1 && columna <= matriz[0].length-1)
        {
        esta = true;
        }
        return esta;    
    }

    public static void pedirJugada (char [][] matriz, char jugador)
    {     

        System.out.print("Jugador "+jugador+" ingrese la fila de su jugada: ");
        int fila = entrada.nextInt(); 
        System.out.print("Jugador "+jugador+" ingrese la columna de su jugada: ");
        int columna = entrada.nextInt();
        if (comprobarCasilla(matriz, fila,columna) == true)
        {            
            matriz[fila][columna] = jugador; 
            imprimirMatriz(matriz, 0, 0);

        }
        else {       
            System.out.print("El casillero esta ocupado, ingrese las coordenadas nuevamente");
            System.out.println();
            pedirJugada(matriz, jugador); 
            }

    }    



    public static void gestionarTurnos (char [][] matriz, char jugador)
    {
//        int f=0;
//        int c=0; 
        if (buscarGanador (matriz, f, c)==1)
            {
                        //gestionarTurnos(matriz, jugador);
                pedirJugada(matriz, jugador); 

                    if (jugador=='X')
                    {               
                        jugador='O';
                        gestionarTurnos(matriz, jugador);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jugador='X';
                        gestionarTurnos (matriz, jugador);
                    }            
            }
        else if (buscarGanador (matriz, f, c)==2)
            {
            System.out.println("Oh!Parece que tenemos un empate!");
            menu();
            }
        else{
            System.out.println("Felicidades"+jugador+". Ganaste!!!");
            }



    }


public static boolean jugadaGanadoraHorizontal (char [][] matriz, int f, int c)
{

   boolean ganaste= false;
        if (matriz[f][c]==matriz[f][c+1]&&matriz[f][c]==matriz[f][c+2] && matriz[f][c+1]!='-')
        {
            ganaste=true;          

        }
        else if(f < matriz.length-1) {

            ganaste = jugadaGanadoraHorizontal(matriz, f+1, c); 
        }
   return ganaste;
}

public static boolean jugadaGanadoraVertical (char [][] matriz, int f, int c)
{
    boolean ganaste= false;
    if (c<=2)
    {
        if (matriz[f][c]==matriz[f + 1][c]&&matriz[f][c]==matriz[f+2][c] && matriz[f][c]!='-')
        {
            ganaste=true;
            System.out.print((matriz[0][c])+ "ha ganado vertical");
        }
        else 
        {
            if(c< matriz.length)
            {
               // ganaste = jugadaGanadoraVertical(matriz, f, c); 
            }

        }
    }
    return ganaste;
}


public static boolean jugadaGanadoraDiagonal (char [][] matriz, int f, int c)
    {
        boolean ganador = false; 
        if (matriz[f][c+2]==matriz[f+1][c+1] && matriz[f][c+2]==matriz[f+2][c] && matriz[f][c+2]!='-') //diagonal derecha
            {
                ganador = true; 
                System.out.print( "ha ganado diagonal");
            }

        return ganador; 
    }

public static int hayEmpate (char matriz [][], int f, int c, int ocurrencia)
    {      
        System.out.print(matriz[f][c] + ""); //muestro el primer elemento

        if(c != matriz[0].length -1 || f!=matriz.length -1) //Estoy en la ultima columna 
        {
            if(c == matriz[0].length - 1)
            {
                f++; //Paso a la siguiente fila
                c = 0; //Comienza de la primer columna
                 if (matriz[f][c]=='-')
                 {
                 ocurrencia++;
                 }
            }
            else {
                   c++; 
                        if (matriz[f][c]=='-')
                         {
                         ocurrencia++;
                         }
                    hayEmpate(matriz, f, c, ocurrencia); 
                }
        }
             return ocurrencia;  

    }


public static int buscarGanador (char matriz [][], int f, int c) 
{
int resultado=0;
if (jugadaGanadoraHorizontal(matriz,f,c)==false)
{
    if (jugadaGanadoraVertical(matriz,f,c)==false)
    {
     if (jugadaGanadoraDiagonal (matriz, f, c)==false)
     {
        if (hayEmpate(matriz, f, c,0)!= 0 )
            {
            resultado=1;//no hay empate, ni jugada ganadora
            }
        else 
           {
           resultado=2;//hay empate
           }
     }
     else
     {
     resultado=3;//ganador diagonal
     }
    }
    else
    {
    resultado=3;//ganador vertical
    }
}
else
{
if (jugadaGanadoraVertical(matriz,f,c)==false)
    {
     if (jugadaGanadoraDiagonal (matriz, f, c)==false)
     {
        if (hayEmpate(matriz, f, c,0)!= 0 )
            {
            resultado=3;
            }
        else 
           {
           resultado=3;
           }
     }
     else
     {
     resultado=3;
     }
    }//Siempre retorna 3 porque ya la horizontal de por si es true
}
return resultado;
}
}
```

Comment: ¿En qué línea es el error? Si no lo dices habría que animarse a examinar todo tu código tratando de adivinar lo que hace. Los mensajes de error suelen mostrar la línea problemática cerca de donde dice  `Caused by ... `

Comment: Como indica @A.Cedano, es más fácil ayudar cuando das más información, en tu caso el mensaje de error. Como ejemplo, me ha tocado hacer exactamente lo que A.Cedano dijo: animarme a examinar todo tu código. Ya tenés la respuesta abajo. Pero no quiero que te acostumbrés a esto, tenés que aprender a preguntar... y a buscar respuestas también.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` significa que estás tratando de acceder a un un arreglo, pero que te estás saliendo de los límites.

En tu caso es causado porque no estás revisando si lo que el jugador está dentro de los límites del tablero de juego. El programa solo te acepta coordenadas de entre cero y dos para `X` y `Y`. Pero el jugador es libre de ingresar un numero mayor a dos, es allí donde se genera el error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Podés arreglarlo así:

```
public static void pedirJugada (char [][] matriz, char jugador)
{     

    System.out.print("Jugador "+jugador+" ingrese la fila de su jugada: ");
    int fila = entrada.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("Jugador "+jugador+" ingrese la columna de su jugada: ");
    int columna = entrada.nextInt();
    if (fila >= 3 || columna >=3) { // Revisar si está dentro de los límites
        System.out.println("Las coordenadas no son correctas");
        System.out.println("Intentelo otra vez");
        pedirJugada(matriz, jugador);
    }
    else if (comprobarCasilla(matriz, fila,columna) == true) // 'else if' para evitar el error.
    {            
        matriz[fila][columna] = jugador; 
        imprimirMatriz(matriz, 0, 0);

    }
    else {       
        System.out.print("El casillero esta ocupado, ingrese las coordenadas nuevamente");
        System.out.println();
        pedirJugada(matriz, jugador); 
        }

}
```

---

PD: Aun con esta reparación, el usuario es libre de ingresar letras o cualquier otro simbolo, lo que generará un `InputMismatchExeption` si no es un número. Te lo dejo de tarea el como evitar eso.